# Получить картинку из Clipboard

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

При попытке возвратить картинку, скопированную в Clipboard, там пусто. В чем проблема? Или можно копировать картинку из richTextBox минуя Clipboard?

```
Clipboard.Clear();
if ((this.richTextBox5.SelectionType & RichTextBoxSelectionTypes.Object) == RichTextBoxSelectionTypes.Object)
{
    richTextBox5.Copy();
    if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
    {
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox1.Image = Clipboard.GetImage();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Пусто");
    }
```

Comment: Ну, если вы поместили в клипборд содержимое RichTextBox, то у вас внутри скорее всего не картинка, а другой формат. (RTF, наверное.)

Comment: А почему pain легко определяет что это картинка и дает ее редактировать

Comment: Хороший вопрос, не знаю. Но вы всё же выяснили бы, в каком конкретно формате картинка. Потому что ваш `MessageBox.Show("Пусто");` не означает, что в буфере обмена пусто, а лишь что там нет картинки.

Comment: для копирование изображения в буфер используйте Clipboard.SetImage()

Answer (score 1):

Метод `Clipboard.ContainsImage()` проверяет наличие в буфере обмена изображения в формате BMP. При копировании из RichText там окажется изображение, скорее всего, в формате EMF. Проверить его наличие можно с помощью вызова `Clipboard.ContainsData(DataFormats.EnhancedMetafile)`.

Теперь необходимо извлечь изображение из буфера обмена. Однако, для класса `Clipboard` извлечение EMF по каким-то причинам не работает: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868816/

Поэтому придется написать дополнительный код, обращающийся к нативному WinAPI для извлечения изображения из буфера:

```
private const int CF_ENHMETAFILE = 14;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool OpenClipboard(IntPtr hWndNewOwner);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int IsClipboardFormatAvailable(int wFormat);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetClipboardData(int wFormat);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int CloseClipboard();

private Image GetImage()
{
    Metafile result = null;
    if (OpenClipboard(this.Handle)) {
        try {
            if (IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_ENHMETAFILE) != 0) {
                var hMeta = GetClipboardData(CF_ENHMETAFILE);
                if (hMeta != IntPtr.Zero)
                    result = new Metafile(hMeta, true);
            }
        } finally {
            CloseClipboard();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Теперь с буфером обмена можно работать:

```
Clipboard.Clear();

if ((richTextBox5.SelectionType & RichTextBoxSelectionTypes.Object) != 0) {
    richTextBox5.Copy();
    if (Clipboard.ContainsData(DataFormats.EnhancedMetafile)) {
        var image = GetImage();
            if (image != null)
                pictureBox1.Image = image;
    }
}
```